# android in-app import csv

Tags: android

I'm trying to import a csv file to auto-populate in-app items.
I use:
(in format `product_id`,`publish_state`,`purchase_type`,`autotranslate`,`locale; title; description`,`autofill`,`country; price`)

```
xxx_10ass,published,managed_by_publisher,false,en_US; 10 yyy; 10 yyy,true,US; 1600000
xxx_50ass,published,managed_by_publisher,false,en_US; 50 yyy; 50 yyy,true,US; 1700000
xxx_100ass,published,managed_by_publisher,false,en_US; 100 yyy; 100 yyy,true,US; 1800000
xxx_500ass,published,managed_by_publisher,false,en_US; 500 yyy; 500 yyy,true,US; 1900000
xxx_1000ass,published,managed_by_publisher,false,en_US; 1000 yyy; 1000 yyy,true,US;2000000
```

I'm getting "There was a problem importing the CSV file."
See here: developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_admin.html under "Adding a batch of items to a product list"

Any idea?

Comment: I count 8 fields in your csv description (format), but only 7 fields in your sample csv file?

Comment: Count the commas, not the semicolons that are part of the field. There are 7 fields in both

Comment: You're right, I stand corrected.

Comment: So, were you going to post the code that generated this "There was a problem importing the CSV file" error or did you want us to guess?  :)

Comment: There is no code. I just try to import a csv to in-app products on the market website. See here: http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_admin.html
under "Adding a batch of items to a product list"

Comment: This being in-app billing related, you'll need to troubleshoot what exactly Google doesn't like about your `CSV` file. I'd start by uploading line by line and go from there. I don't think there's much any of us can do for you here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found solution.
The format should be:
xxx_10ass,published,managed_by_publisher,false,en_US; 10 yyy; 10 yyy,true,1600000
and not
xxx_10ass,published,managed_by_publisher,false,en_US; 10 yyy; 10 yyy,true,US; 1600000