# Android in-app products import from csv file

Tags: android, csv, import, in-app

Can anyone make correct `CSV` file for importing in-app products? 
All my attempts were failed.

First option:

```
test,published,managed_by_publisher,false,en_US;name;desc,false,US;1990000
```

The result is: **"The first defined currency of Product IDs [test] has to be [ru]."** (I am from Russia but it never sets some country settings).

After I set *autofill* to *true*:

```
test,published,managed_by_publisher,false,en_US;name;desc,true,default_price_in_home_currency;1990000
```

The result is: **"There was a problem importing the CSV file."**

Even if I export and then import the same file, I got these errors.
And I can't find any information, except [android in-app import csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8721151/android-in-app-import-csv) and http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_admin.html#billing-bulk-add

Comment: In new version of developer console import work fine.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
test,published,managed_by_publisher,false,en_US;name;desc,true,1990000
```

Answer (score 0):

this is for colombian values, and spanish latin american

```
onemarker,published,managed_by_publisher,false,es_419; One Payment; One Payment,true,11900000000

twomarker,published,managed_by_publisher,false,es_419; Two Payment; Two payment,true,23800000000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use my utils to create a valid csv to import in-app products into the Play Market

Good luck!